# C# Client connecting through a Proxy Server to a Chat Server gets lost

Tags: c#, sockets, silverlight, proxy-server

My Issue is I have a Silverlight C# client that uses NetSockets to connect to a C# Server. The issue is when we have clients who are behind a proxy server, there is a problem connecting to the server. We get the inbound connection and then we can’t seem to communicate anymore. Firewalls have been checked both on the proxy server and client machines. we have confirmed their port is open.

Here are excerpts from my server code:

```
public void StartServer()
    {
        //Silverlight port range: 4502-4532
        _socketListener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        IPEndPoint ipLocal = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 4530);
        _socketListener.Bind(ipLocal);
        _socketListener.Listen(4);

          while (true)
        {
            // Set the event to nonsignaled state.
            _allDone.Reset();
            Console.WriteLine("Begin Accept Connections");
            // create the call back for any client connections...
            _socketListener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(HandleClientConnectionRequest), null);
            Console.WriteLine("Accept Done");
            // Wait until a connection is made before continuing.
            _allDone.WaitOne();
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for connection.....");

        }
}
```

This is Callback on Connection:

```
public void HandleClientConnectionRequest(IAsyncResult asyn)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Request For Connection.");
            // Signal the main thread to continue.
            _allDone.Set();

            //Create a packet to hold the client state
            CSockPack clientSocket = new CSockPack();
            clientSocket.cSocket = _socketListener.EndAccept(asyn); ;


            //Wait for incoming data
            WaitForData(clientSocket);

            Console.WriteLine("New client connected.");
           // SendData("New client connected");

            clientSocket.cSocket.Send(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Authenticate<end>"));
        }
        catch (ObjectDisposedException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("OnClientConnection: Socket has been closed\n");
        }
        catch (SocketException se)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(se.Message);
        }

    }
```

And on the Silverlight side:

```
public Socket _socket;
public DnsEndPoint _endPoint;
public SocketAsyncEventArgs _sendEventArgs;
```

This is in Application Start in Silverlight:

```
_endPoint = new DnsEndPoint(Application.Current.Host.Source.DnsSafeHost, 4530);
_socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

SocketAsyncEventArgs args = new SocketAsyncEventArgs();
args.UserToken = _socket;
args.RemoteEndPoint = _endPoint;
args.Completed += new EventHandler<SocketAsyncEventArgs>(OnSocketConnectCompleted);

_socket.ConnectAsync(args);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you see this? _The security policy system in the Silverlight 3 runtime requires that a policy file be downloaded from a network resource before a network connection is allowed to access that resource._ https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296248(v=vs.95)

Comment: mario, yes I have and we do use it. without that, I don't think anyone would be able to connect. I do have users who can attach and use the system without problems. But some users, esp those with proxy servers, are having difficulty.

Comment: did you tried bypassing the proxy

Comment: Malcom, how do I bypass a proxy when the proxy belongs to the client? Im not sure what you mean by bypass the proxy...